# Android Room Persistence Library TypeConverter unknown issue

Tags: java, android

I'm having hard times trying to save my Entity into Room Persistence Database. As far as I understand RPL (RoomPersistenceLibrary) will accept only primitive types so I need to convert two of my fields: `Calendar mStartDate`, `Calendar mEndTime` into Strings using Typeconverters (both fileds are used to set start and end date - minute,hour,day,month,year every time I create my `WeekViewEvent`'s - see the constructor).

So I've created one, but there's still something wrong with it as Android Studio keep displaying me the same error over and over again:
*Cannot figure out how to save this field into database (..)*
[image]
I'm not able to track the error down as the console doesn't show code's line.

**Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?**
Thank you in advance for any help! :)

WeekViewEvent.class:

```
@Entity
public class WeekViewEvent implements Serializable {

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
private long mId;
private String mName;
private String mLocation;
private int mColor;
private boolean mAllDay;
private Shader mShader;
private String Identifier;

@TypeConverters({WeekViewEventCONVERTER.class})
private Calendar mStartTime;
@TypeConverters({WeekViewEventCONVERTER.class})
private Calendar mEndTime;


public WeekViewEvent(long id, String name, String location, String identifier, int color, int startYear, int startMonth, int startDay, int startHour, int startMinute, int endYear, int endMonth, int endDay, int endHour, int endMinute) {
    this.mId = id;
    this.mStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.mStartTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
    this.mStartTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth - 1);
    this.mStartTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
    this.mStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
    this.mStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinute);
    this.mEndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.mEndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, endYear);
    this.mEndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, endMonth - 1);
    this.mEndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, endDay);
    this.mEndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endHour);
    this.mEndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endMinute);
    this.mName = name;
    this.Identifier = identifier;
    this.mLocation = location;
    this.mColor = color;}
...
}
```

WeekViewEventCONVERTER.class:

```
 @TypeConverter
public static Calendar fromString (String value){
    Type calendarType = new TypeToken<Calendar>() {}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, calendarType);
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromCalendar (Calendar mStartTime){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(mStartTime);
    return json;
}
```

}

and WeekViewEventDAO:

```
@Dao
public interface WeekViewEventDAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
public long insertWeekViewEvent (WeekViewEvent event);

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
public void updateWeekViewEvent (WeekViewEvent event);

@Delete
public void deleteWeekViewEvent (WeekViewEvent event);

@Query("DELETE FROM WeekViewEvent")
public void deleteAllWeekViewEvents();

@Query("SELECT * FROM WeekViewEvent")
WeekViewEvent getWeekViewEvent();

@Query("SELECT * FROM WeekViewEvent")
public List<WeekViewEvent> getAllWeekVieweventsList();}
```

Comment: There are *much* more efficient ways to convert a `Calendar` to a valid column type, such as using the milliseconds-since-the-Unix-epoch value (e.g., `getTimeAsMillis()`). Beyond that... why does an object that is both `Serializable` and supposed to go in a database have a `Shader` in the first place? If that `Shader` is [this `Shader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html), that is something that belongs in the UI layer, not the data representation layer.

Comment: Haven't thought about converting it to miliseconds - good idea!
To tell the truth it's a library and I do not use Shader field (yes the Shader we're talking about is THAT Shader) :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have no type converter for this field:

```
private Shader mShader;
```

Try adding `@Ignore` to mark it as non - persistent.

Comment: Ignoring Shader mShader did the job!
Thank you Danail! Have a good day! :)

Comment: @Matt but how do i make a converter for Shader class if i want to make it persistent